# Clear columns of selected cell row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to clear contents of **selected** row (not delete entire row). Can someone help?

[image]

Eg: `D3` is selected
Clear `D3,E3,F3,G3,H3` but not delete the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

You are looking for the [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee).

The following script will clear `D:H` of the row/cell you selected in column D.

### Code snippet:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // put the name of your sheet here
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()==sheetName && range.getColumn() == 4){
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),4,1,5).clearContent();
  }  
}
```

I hope it is clear that this is a trigger function. Namely, you are not supposed to manually execute it by yourself but it will be triggered upon selections in the sheet (see Illustration).

**Illustration:**

[image]

**Possible Restriction:**

- `onSelectionChange` is a little bit buggy but it can work really well. If it does not work in the beginning, disable the v8 run time environment, refresh the script editor page and then enable v8 environment again. You might need to wait or refresh the page again but it will eventually work. [Please read the related issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180042705).

Comment: I'll try it out soon. But I don't want to delete it just by selecting the cell. I need a keyboard key or button to trigger it

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the cells the you wish to clear and hit backspace to clear the contents of the cells.

Alternatively, run this function in the script editor:

```js
function clearData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_SHEET').getRange('D3:H3');    
  ss.clear();
}
```

Comment: Yeah but it can be D3, D4, D5, D6 and so on. I need it to be the selected cell (variable

Comment: For that, either change the range in parentheses and keep running the function for each range you wish to clear. Alternatively, copy the second and third rows (var ss =... and ss.clear...) and add the ranges you wish to clear after in the parentheses after .getRange. also don't forget to change the "ss" to ss1, ss2, ss3 and so on for each new range that you defined

Comment: I don't think anyone will define 100+ rows.. any better solution? Also how will it know which row to clear?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Deleterow() {
  const sheetName = "Anju"; // put the name of your sheet here
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()==sheetName && range.getColumn() == 4){
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),4,1,5).clearContent();
  }  
}
```